# divide at most N non distinct balls to M distinct bins

Tags: combinatorics

A bit different from the uestions already asked here.
I have N balls and M distinct bins, I want to divide up to N of my balls to those bins (meaning either 0 balls, or only one ball ,...)
How many ways are there?

My calculation so far:

if I want to divide exactly r balls to m bins than the formula is: `M+r-1 choose M`
than I need to sum all of those calculations from 0 to N and that's where I get stuck, Can I get some help?
I think the answer should be `M+N choose M`, so maybe someone can explain how he gets to this result in a different way.

BTW, the motivation for this question is calculating the dimension of RM[m,r] if it matters.

Comment: Try adding one more bin, the "didn't get put in any others" bin. Now you're distributing $N$ items to $M+1$ bins, so you get ${M+1} \choose N$.

Comment: right, that simple... tnx